# When calculating first moments of mass in cylindrical coordinates, can we use $r,\theta$ instead of $x,y$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, moment

Usually when we want to find the center of mass of a 3D body, we need to find the 
first moments of mass about $x,y,z$, call them $M_x,M_y,M_z$. Defined by
$$
M_x = \iiint x\rho \ dV,
$$
where $\rho$ is the density function.

However in cylindrical coordinates ($z=z,\ x=r\cos{\theta},\ y=r\sin{\theta}$), we still calculate $M_x,M_y,M_z$. What I want to know is why don't we find $M_z, M_\theta, M_r$? Does this not lead to the following coordinates of the center of mass:
$$
(\bar{z},\bar{\theta}, \bar{r}) = \left(\frac{M_z}{M}, \frac{M_\theta}{M},
\frac{M_r}{M} \right),
$$
where $M$ is the mass of the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your proposed $z,\theta,r$ method doesn't work.

Consider just a cylinder, centered at the origin, and let's look at $M_r=\int\!\!\int\!\!\int r \rho\ dV$.

Even without doing the calculation, we can see that $M_r$ will be something greater than zero, since $r \ge 0$.

This will give your $\bar r = {M_r/ M} \ge 0$.

But one can clearly see by symmetry that the center of mass is at $z=0$, $r=0$, and $\theta$ is anything/undefined.

So you see, trying to do this as you suggest -- calculating the mass-weighted value of $r$ -- isn't giving the center of mass.

Comment: Thank you very much！